# App stays in the background and memory was taken by other app,then click the app to front,what will happen in detail?

Tags: android

The detailed question is :
1.Whether the activity clicking order will get restore.In other words,if i click the back button again and again, whether the app's activity order will be normal.
2.what life cycle in activity will be triggered in last activity?Is it the same with the normal activity jump?
3.Was the state stored in physical memory(like sdcard)?How can i judge whether the important state was lost.

Comment: Research more about Activity Launch mode, BackStack and Activity'life cycle will help you understand this. Actually I think you didn't clearly understand them, so your question is really difficult to understand. Cheer!

Comment: 1. Yes 2.Yes 3. No, it is stored in the RAM memory.

Comment: Activity will be created again if it was destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html):

Once an activity starts it goes to `onCreate` -> `onStart` -> `onResume`. If you minimize an activity (usually with the `Home` key) it will run `onPause` -> `onStop` and when android runs out of memory (because new app needs memory) then android will call `onSaveInstance` (where you save all the data you want) on your activity, then it will destroy it, calling `onDestroy`.

The next time the activity runs it will start again from `onCreate` and the rest, but it will pass a `Bundle` on the `onCreate` with the data you saved previously, for you to restore them. It will also run `onRestoreState` which gets the `Bundle` as well (you can use either one).

Basically, if `onRestoreState` runs, it means your app is restoring, or inside your `onCreate` check if the given `Bundle` is null, if it isn't then your activity is resuming.

I'm not sure if data are saved on sdcard, but I guess they are saved somewhere on physical memory, so android can free some RAM for another app.